# Is Flash.UI.GameInput not supported in Windows?

Tags: air

I'm experimenting with the alleged native controller support of Adobe Air. It seems that Flash.UI.GameInput is the way to go, but when I call:

`Flash.UI.GameInput.isSupported`

...it always returns false.

Running AIR 3.7, Flashdevelop 4.4.2, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Not in AIR 3.7, no.

However, if you move to AIR 3.8 the first steps of Windows/Desktop support has been added.  I can confirm that it works with a Wired (Official) Xbox 360 controller on Windows - although there is a pretty serious caveat in that there appears to be a 1-second, recurring timer setup by the GameInput API.

Even in an incredibly simple application - *just* using GameInput API - we see a 150ms usage spike on the Timer event that the API sets up... a huge drop from 25fps to 6fps!

It's even more noticeable in a larger project, such as one with Stage3D and running at 60fps, as the drop can hit your frame rate down to the low 30's!  This is what I'm seeing on Windows, not necessarily on Android, as the API was originally for.

Answer (score 0):

Update: yes, it now is supported starting in Flash Player 11.8/11.9 and AIR 3.7/3.8. It works the same in AIR and (web) Flash Player.